# Using a while loop to create a new variable based on duplicated values in R

Tags: r, while-loop

So I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
group  ID
aa     123
ab     123
bb     345
bb     345
bb     999
bb     999
cc     567
cd     567
```

When the ID is the same, the group should be equal to the second entry for that ID. So the corrected data should be this:

```
group  ID   group2
aa     123  ab
ab     123  ab
bb     345  bb
bb     345  bb
bb     999  bb
bb     999  bb
cc     567  cd
cd     567  cd
```

I also need to create a new variable to store the correct group. Here is what I have been trying:

```
n <- 1 + (1:(as.numeric(nrow(data))))
l <- 1:(as.numeric(nrow(data)))
while (data[n,1] == data[l,1]) { data$group2 <- data[n,1] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  After grouping by 'ID', select the second observation of 'group' and assign (`:=`) it to 'group2'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, group2 := group[2], ID]
df1
#   group  ID group2
#1:    aa 123     ab
#2:    ab 123     ab
#3:    bb 345     bb
#4:    bb 345     bb
#5:    bb 999     bb
#6:    bb 999     bb
#7:    cc 567     cd
#8:    cd 567     cd
```

Comment: We were working on the same solution at the same time. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do all in one process, you want to tell R that you want the second element of `group` in `group2` for each ID group. If `group` is in character, you can do the following. Your data is called `mydf`.

```
mydf %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(group2 = group[2])

#  group    ID group2
#  <chr> <int>  <chr>
#1    aa   123     ab
#2    ab   123     ab
#3    bb   345     bb
#4    bb   345     bb
#5    bb   999     bb
#6    bb   999     bb
#7    cc   567     cd
#8    cd   567     cd
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `group` column is a character and not a factor, the following trick using `dplyr` package will mostly work:

```
library(dplyr)
answer = data %>% mutate(group2 = ifelse(ID == lead(ID), lead(group), group))
```

I say "mostly work" because the last item will have a `group2` value of `NA`.  That's easily fixed, though:

```
answer$group2[nrow(answer)] = answer$group[nrow(answer)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I knew there had to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: Thanks!  If you find this answer useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In base R

```
df$group2 = df$group[ave(1:NROW(df), df$ID, FUN = max)]
#If each ID can have more than two rows
#and you specifically want the value from second row, use 
#df$group[ave(1:NROW(df), df$ID, FUN = function(x) x[2])]
df
#  group  ID group2
#1    aa 123     ab
#2    ab 123     ab
#3    bb 345     bb
#4    bb 345     bb
#5    bb 999     bb
#6    bb 999     bb
#7    cc 567     cd
#8    cd 567     cd
```

You could also use a `for` loop but its not really necessary

```
group2 = c()
for(x in df$ID){
    temp = subset(df, df$ID == x)
    group2 = c(group2, temp$group[2])
}
group2
#[1] "ab" "ab" "bb" "bb" "bb" "bb" "cd" "cd"
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(group = c("aa", "ab", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", 
"cc", "cd"), ID = c(123L, 123L, 345L, 345L, 999L, 999L, 567L, 
567L)), .Names = c("group", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```